# What was offered to Rey?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Rey is told that she was offered something

> by the dark side cave while Luke is training her and she didn't even try to refuse it.

What did it offer her?

> was it information about her parents?

Comment: As with most of your other questions. While good questions and very interesting, I fear we will have to wait for a future work to enlighten us on the matter.

Comment: She went there expecting to find information about her parents, so I'd say yes.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are about right with your guess, I think it is not just that but

> Who she is

It is a question that has been asked to her at least by Kylo Ren (in the last film) and Luke in this one. (I have a feeling others ask it too but can't remember specifically.)

It is also a question the audience had asked since she turned up.

To which the answer seems to be

> Nobody from nowhere

Which would also apply to Anakin, come to think of it.

Comment: In episode VII, Maz asks Han, "Who's the girl?"